# What does yarn (package manager) stand for?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I recently bumped into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531942/why-is-npms-name-not-node-package-manager) which was explaining the real meaning of the NPM name.
I then decided to look up for what does YARN mean (not the Hadoop yarn, Yet Another Resource Negotiator) but the YARN package manager. Is it just a name?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not directly related to programming.

Comment: I found the answer to the question valuable

Comment: Please correct the link to NPM story

Comment: Yet Another Replacing NPM

Answer (score 14):

It's just a name.

They wanted to differentiate their brand and three-letter acronyms ending on "pm" are too common, so they discarded their original idea and just chose "Yarn".

One of Yarn's developers, Sebastian McKenzie (aka Sebastian, @sebmck), [tweeted](https://twitter.com/sebmck/status/902899559705272320?s=20) that the name was originally supposed to be

> kpm (kittens packet manager)

When asked why it changed the [reply](https://twitter.com/sebmck/status/902900008139317248?s=20) was:

> Lack of orginality. [a-z]pm are basically all taken anyway and brand differentiation is important.

This was also asked on [github](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4536) and confirmed by Konstantin Raev (aka bestander).

Answer (score 3):

For your information,
Yarn means literally "yarn".

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/868

> Yarn is named after knitting yarn which is the foundation of some clothing and connects all the pieces together. We consider Yarn to do the same thing for dependency management.